# where can i change the url in cart that directs to checkout onepage?

Tags: onepage-checkout, ce-1.9.1.0, shopping-cart

Magento 1.9.1.0

In header i have the shopping cart displaying:

an icon (which links to domain.nl/checkout/cart)
the link saying: x item(s) which also links to that url

but, when hovering over these 2 it shows a small dropdown with the cart contents and in it is a button "checkout"

that links to domain.nl/checkout/onepage ...

What file would i need to edit to change that url also to domain.nl/checkout/cart and it would be great if anyone could also tell me which line to edit

Because many people seem to click checkout, therefore missing the opportunity to check cart contents and entering discount code.

site can be found [here](https://www.blinckstar.nl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have use a theme. If this `theme is develop basic of magento RWD theme` ,then you can get this link at

> app/design/frontend/YourPackage/Your
>   Theme/checkout/cart/minicart/items.phtml

The function `getCheckoutUrl()` is generate the url;

**If you does not find that theme need enable template hint**

- [sweettoothrewards](http://help.sweettoothrewards.com/article/434-how-do-i-turn-on-template-path-hints)
- [excellencemagentoblog](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/09/07/magento-template-path-hints-magento/)

Comment: It was in different location, but you set me in the right direction. app / design / frontend / default / themename / template / magentothem / ajaxcartsuper / checkout / cart / topcart.phtml ... thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

From my phone now, you are probably looking for checkout/cart/minicart.phtml inside your theme folder. Anyway you should be able to add a coupon from the one page checkout you are using.

Comment: in checkout/cart there is the option to add the coupon, in checkout/onepage there is not... this last page is the stepped checkout on one page...